# Multithreading in Ada

Tags: multithreading, task, ada

I'm learning Ada and I've some problems in understanding the concurrency models. The following test application shall create 3 tasks which run in parallel and simply print a range of numbers. If I use a task without `entry` then everything is fine, but if I use entries the procedure call blocks and no concurrency can happen at all.

I understand that there is a possibility to achieve mutual exclusion and synchronized execution, but I am not able to understand how to detach the tasks so that it may even possible to create several of them.

q_multithreading.ads:

```
package Q_MULTITHREADING is

  task type TASK_LOOP is
  end TASK_LOOP;

  type TASK_LOOP_ACCESS is access TASK_LOOP;

  --===========================================================================

  task type TASK_ENTRY_LOOP is
    entry P_ITERATE(to : in Integer);
  end TASK_ENTRY_LOOP;

  type TASK_ENTRY_LOOP_ACCESS is access TASK_ENTRY_LOOP;

  --===========================================================================

  procedure P_EXECUTE_NO_ENTRY;

  procedure P_EXECUTE_ENTRY(to : in Integer);

end Q_MULTITHREADING;
```

q_multithreading.adb:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;

package body Q_MULTITHREADING is

  V_ID_COUNTER : Integer := 1;

  --===========================================================================

  task body TASK_LOOP is

    V_ID : Integer := -1;

  begin

    V_ID := V_ID_COUNTER;
    V_ID_COUNTER := V_ID_COUNTER + 1;

    for i in 1 .. 15 loop
      delay 0.1;
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("[" & Integer'Image(V_ID) & "] " &
                             Integer'Image(i));
    end loop;

    V_ID_COUNTER := V_ID_COUNTER - 1;

  end TASK_LOOP;

  --===========================================================================

  task body TASK_ENTRY_LOOP is

    V_ID : Integer := -1;

  begin

    V_ID := V_ID_COUNTER;
    V_ID_COUNTER := V_ID_COUNTER + 1;

    accept P_ITERATE(to : in Integer) do
      for i in 1 .. to loop
        delay 0.1;
        Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("[" & Integer'Image(V_ID) & "] " &
                               Integer'Image(i));
      end loop;
    end P_ITERATE;

    V_ID_COUNTER := V_ID_COUNTER - 1;

  end TASK_ENTRY_LOOP;

  --===========================================================================

  procedure P_EXECUTE_NO_ENTRY is

    V_TASK1, V_TASK2, V_TASK3 : TASK_LOOP_ACCESS;

  begin

    V_ID_COUNTER := 1;

    Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Starting task 1 ...");
    V_TASK1 := new TASK_LOOP;

    Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Starting task 2 ...");
    V_TASK2 := new TASK_LOOP;

    Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Starting task 3 ...");
    V_TASK3 := new TASK_LOOP;

  end P_EXECUTE_NO_ENTRY;

  --===========================================================================

  procedure P_EXECUTE_ENTRY(to : in Integer) is

    V_TASK1, V_TASK2, V_TASK3 : TASK_ENTRY_LOOP_ACCESS;

  begin

    V_ID_COUNTER := 1;

    V_TASK1 := new TASK_ENTRY_LOOP;
    Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Starting task 1 ...");
    V_TASK1.P_ITERATE(to); -- blocking

    V_TASK2 := new TASK_ENTRY_LOOP;
    Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Starting task 2 ...");
    V_TASK2.P_ITERATE(to - 5); -- blocking

    V_TASK3 := new TASK_ENTRY_LOOP;
    Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Starting task 3 ...");
    V_TASK3.P_ITERATE(to + 3); -- blocking

  end P_EXECUTE_ENTRY;

end Q_MULTITHREADING;
```

As I already mentioned if I call `P_EXECUTE_NO_ENTRY` the output is disordered and the tasks are detached from the main thread. On the other hand `*P_EXECUTE_ENTRY(to : in Integer)` leads to a blocking procedure call and the output is like an application which doesn't use tasks.

How are tasks with entries concurrently executed in Ada?

Furthermore, do I have to deallocate the tasks as well? (examples from the web didn't do it)

Comment: You don't have to create tasks with `new`.  You can also simply declare objects of a task type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you say

```
accept P_ITERATE(to : in Integer) do
  for i in 1 .. to loop
    delay 0.1;
    Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("[" & Integer'Image(V_ID) & "] " &
                           Integer'Image(i));
  end loop;
end P_ITERATE;
```

the caller is blocked until the `end P_ITERATE`, so the entire loop completes before `P_EXECUTE_ENTRY` can continue to the next task.

To fix this, save the loop count in a task variable and execute the loop outside the `accept`:

```
accept P_ITERATE(to : in Integer) do
  count := to;
end P_ITERATE;
for i in 1 .. count loop
  delay 0.1;
  Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("[" & Integer'Image(V_ID) & "] " &
                         Integer'Image(i));
end loop;
```

As for deallocating the tasks - most programs that terminate wouldn’t bother, because the operating system deallocates memory on process exit. In this case, you probably wouldn’t get round to deallocating before the task has actually terminated; deallocating a running task may lead to unexpected behaviour. How to manage this should be a different question, I think.

Answer (score 4):

Tasks are synchronized during a rendezvous (i.e. as long as you are inside an `accept` statement).

Typically you will limit an `accept` statement to copying the passed arguments to/from the task containing the `accept` statement:

```
accept Start (Steps : in Positive) do
   Count := Steps;
end Start;

for I in 1 .. Count loop
   ...
```